# response map is nil compojure

Tags: clojure, compojure, ring

I just don't understand anything.
When I do `curl -X GET --header 'Accept: application/json' 'http://localhost:3000/api/hello'` from my swagger I get a nice answer  `{"result":1}`.
However, when I try something like: `http://localhost:3000/api/hello?criteria=drf`, the server gives me `java.lang.NullPointerException: Response map is nil`. I am pretty sure it's not nil, since I still get my `{"result":1}` back on the screen.
But after that first error, every `GET /hello` request, without any query parameters, gives an error on server side, while still giving the right answer to the client?

And I need to restart server in order to make the error stop. Which works, until the first request with query params....

```
(ns swag.handler
  (:require [compojure.api.sweet :refer :all]
            [ring.util.http-response :refer :all]
            [clojure.java.jdbc :as j]
            [clojure.core.match :as match]
            [clojure.spec.alpha :s s]
            )
(def app
  (api
    {:swagger
     {:ui "/"
      :spec "/swagger.json"
      :data {:info {:title "Trash"
                    :description "Compojure Api example"}
             :tags [{:name "api", :description "some apis"}]}}}

    (context "/api" []
      :tags ["api"]

      (GET "/plus" []
        :return {:result Long}
        :query-params [x :- Long, y :- Long]
        :summary "adds two numbers together"
        (ok {:result (+ x y)}))

      (GET "/hello" []
        :query-params [& z]
        (let [criteria (:criteria z) values (:date z)]
          (println z)
          (ok {:result 1})))
))
  )
```

Comment: Won't adding a GET for "/hello?" fix the problem? Seems like the server has crashed and so become non-responsive but the browser is still responding through its cache somehow.

Comment: I can not reproduce this error with your def in the example of compojure-api
: https://github.com/metosin/compojure-api/tree/master/examples/simple. The Get with the parameter works.

Answer (score 3):

If you're getting this message, check for favicon.ico request in the browser.

This may trigger a response map is null because no route is configured to handle it.

Comment: this question is 3 years old.. also I gave up on clojure because un-debuggable

Comment: I added for future reference because I've just run into the same issue :)

Comment: Whats the easiest way to fix?

Answer (score 0):

Issue for us was we needed trailing `/s` on the endpoint that was giving us this error (was looking at your q while we were debugging, but just solved).